# How do I access the Dropbox proprieties and choose the folders I want to sync?

Tags: sync, directory, dropbox

My Ubuntu partition has 60Gb while my Dropbox account has 35Gb. I don't want to sync all the Dropbox folders, just one of them. Do somebody know how I access the Dropbox proprieties to choose the folder I want to sync?

I remember that in Windows I would go to the Dropbox icon, next to the clock, then a right click, access the proprieties and then I could choose which folders I'd like to sync.

I feel bad to ask this, it was supposed to be simple and I can't find any solution online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called [Selective Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en). Offical linux docs are in the former link, but I will copy them here for reference as 04/01/14.

> Select which folders to sync on Linux
>
> - Click on the Dropbox icon from the menu bar. If you don't see the Dropbox icon, press the white up arrow to see all system tray icons.
> - Select Preferences.
> - Click the Account tab.
> - Click the Selective Sync button.
>
> A window will appear with a list of all the top level folders in your
>   Dropbox folder. The folders with a check next to them will be synced
>   to your computer. Uncheck any folders that you don't need to sync to
>   your computer's hard drive. When you're done, select OK. Any folders
>   you deselected will be removed from your hard drive, but will still be
>   available through the website and on any computers linked to your
>   Dropbox account.
>
> Use the Advanced View button to drill down into the folders in your
>   Dropbox. Click on the arrow next to the folders in your Dropbox to
>   drill down and check or uncheck folders deep within your Dropbox
>   hierarchy. From the command line
>
> If you have the Dropbox command line instructions script, then all you
>   need to do to add a folder to the Selective Sync "do not sync" list is
>   enter the following command in your Terminal.
>
> ```
> /path/to/dropbox.py exclude add ~/Dropbox/path/to/folder/
> ```
>
> Simply substitute the /path/to/ to the actual paths to the CLI script
>   and the folder or file, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a fun time with Dropbox trying to download my life history onto a very old computer running 32-bit Ubuntu.  Wish this answer was right here when I went into action to reverse that process.  Just open a terminal and run

```
cd ~                               # Got to your home directory
dropbox exclude add ./Dropbox/*    # and unsync every file from the Dropbox folder.
```

You may have to run this a few times as Dropbox downloads your file list.  Then you can add back your necessary folders with

```
dropbox exclude remove ./Dropbox/picturesOfKittens
```

This is assuming that you are successfully able to run the `dropbox` command.  If the command doesn't run you can try downloading the `dropbox.py` Python script from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/linux-commands>.).